# Как сгенерировать иерархический JSON класса?

Tags: c#, json, serialize

Есть класс `Recycler`. Примерная его структура:

```
Recycler {
    string Url
    string Data
}
```

Далее я добавляю данные в массив данных этого класса:

```
List<Recycler> list = new List<Recycler>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Recycler rec = new Recycler();
    rec.Url = "www.site.ru";
    rec.Data = "Пример" + i;   
    list.Add(rec);
}

var m = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list); // Сериализую класс
```

И в конце сериализую его. Получаю такой JSON:

```
[{"Url":"www.ya.ru", "Data":"Пример1"},{"Url":"www.ya.ru", "Data":"Пример2"}]
```

Но видно, что есть дублирование данных.
Как привести его к иерархическому виду? Чтобы получилось:

```
[{
    "url" : "www.ya.ru",
    "childitems" : [{
        "Data" : "Пример1"
    }, {
        "Data" : "Пример2"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классы для конкретного json можно сгенерировать прямо в студии - Edit / Paste Special / Paste JSON as Classes:

```
public class RecyclerData
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public ChildData[] childitems { get; set; }
}

public class ChildData
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

`List<RecyclerData>` сериализуется в ваш JSON.

```
var list = new List<RecyclerData>()
{
    new RecyclerData
    {
        url = "www.ya.ru",
        childitems = new ChildData[]
        {
            new ChildData { Data = "Пример1" },
            new ChildData { Data = "Пример1" }
        }
    }
};

var string1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

Ваш `List<Recycler>` в него можно преобразовать как:

```
var dtoList = list
    .GroupBy(l => l.Url)
    .Select(g => new RecyclerData
    {
        url = g.Key,
        childitems = g.Select(d => new ChildData { Data = d.Data }).ToArray()
    }).ToList();

var m = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtoList);
```